# Calculate approximately the eigenvalue using the Inverse Iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have the matrix  \begin{equation*}A=\begin{pmatrix}7 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{4} & -5 & 1 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{3}{2}\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

with the eigenvalues $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \lambda_3$.

Using the Gershgorin lemma I want to estimate the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ (using the smallest center of a Gershgorin circle).

The circles are \begin{align*}&K_1=\left \{|x-7|\leq \left |\frac{1}{4}\right |+\left |\frac{1}{2}\right |\right \}=\left \{|x-7|\leq 0.75\right \} \\ 
&K_2=\left \{|x-(-5)|\leq \left |\frac{1}{4}\right |+|1|\right \}=\left \{|x+5|\leq 1.25\right \} \\ 
&K_3=\left \{\left |x-\frac{3}{2}\right |\leq \left |\frac{1}{2}\right |+|1|\right \}=\left \{\left |x-\frac{3}{2}\right |\leq 1.5\right \} \end{align*}

Therefore, we get \begin{align*} -6.25\leq &\lambda_1 \leq -3.75 \\ 0\leq &\lambda_2\leq 3 \\ 6.25\leq &\lambda_3 \leq 7.75 \end{align*}  right?

Next, I want to make a shift around this estimate and calculate approximately the eigenvalue using the Inverse Iteration (3 steps) with initial vector $x^{(0)} = (−1,0,0)^T$.

We have to consider the matrix $(A-sI)^{-1}$ and apply the power method, or not?But which $s$ do we have to take? Do we maybe consider as $s$ a number in the interval $[-6.25, -3.75]$, i.e. the interval of $\lambda_1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

When you choose s to to be within domain $K_1$, the inverse powermethod will converge to the eigenvektor of the eigenpair $(\lambda_1,  v_1)$. The closer s to the actual value of $\lambda_1$ is, the faster is the convergence.

Comment: The eigenvalues are: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B7,+1%2F4,+1%2F2%7D,%7B1%2F4,-5,1%7D,%7B1%2F2,1,3%2F2%7D%7D So, can we get for example $s=-5$ ?

Comment: if you select s=-5, you should converge to the eigenvector (0.0967097, -6.70119, 1)

Comment: So, we have to find the inverse matrix $(A+5I)^{-1}$ and then apply the power method for the matrix $(A+5I)^{-1}$ and the initial vector $x^{(0}$, right?

Comment: You choose a $v_0$, an initial guess for the eigenvector ( not [0,0,0] ) and then you iterate as following: $v_{i+1}= \frac{(A+5I)^{-1}v_{i}}{||(A+5I)^{-1}v_{i}||} $ and you should compute the inverse once, not for every iteration.

Comment: As initial vector it is given the $x^{(0)}=(-1,0,0)^T$. What do you mean by  "you should compute the inverse once, not for every iteration" ? I have calculated (if I am not mistaken) $$\|(A+5I)^{-1}x^{(3)}\|_{\infty}=\frac{9255292892}{1414521867}\approx 6.54$$ Can we conclude from that something about the eigenvalues of $A$? Does it maybe hold that the eigenvalue of $A+5I$ will then be $\frac{1}{6.5}$ and the eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda$ such that $|\lambda+5|=\frac{1}{6.5}$ ?

Comment: You keep -5 as your approx. eigenvalue. This iteration computes the corresponding eigenvector.

Comment: But in some notes there is that $\|Av_k\|_{\infty}\rightarrow |\lambda_m|$ where $\lambda_m$ is the largest in absolute value eigenvalue. Is this not true?

Comment: There is the powermethod which computes the eigenvalue with the largest absolute value and there is the inverse power method which computes the eigenvector to the corresponding approximate eigenvalue, in this case -5.